# How to start emacs from the terminal with an emacs command that runs soon after emacs is opened

Tags: terminal, emacs

Is there a way to launch Emacs from terminal and execute some Emacs command automatically soon after Emacs is launched (the command to be executed inside of emacs is provided along with the Emacs-launching command executed from the shell.)

What I want to do exactly is to have a command to launch Emacs and then open a new empty buffer and activate org mode inside of this buffer.
I want something that might look like this

```
emacs -fs --command="evil-buffer-new && org-mode"
```

I want the `-fs` flag because I want Emacs to open in full-screen in this case.

## Update

`--eval` flag didn't work. Forget about `evil-buffer-new`, I have tried something as simple as:

```
emacs --eval="(org-mode)" txt.txt
```

`txt.txt` is an empty text file created before executing the above command (and please don't ask me why I didn't use `.org` file extension).
after Emacs opened, **org-mode wasn't active**. I had to run `pp-eval-expression` then `(org-mode)` to activate it, and then it worked.

Am I missing something here? How about rephrasing the question like this:

How to open an empty text file (having `.txt` file extension) with Emacs from the terminal and have org-mode activated in that buffer automatically?

Comment: `emacs --eval="(org-mode)" txt.txt` is going to invoke org-mode on whatever buffer happens to be current when that code gets evaluated.  Don't *assume* the visiting of `txt.txt` will happen exactly when you want it to; you need to control the sequence. Do what I showed in my answer, but use `(find-file ...)` before the call to `(org-mode)`.

Answer (score 1):

See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs)Action Arguments` or even just run `emacs --help` -- there are several options for loading and evaluating arbitrary code.

> ```
> --command="evil-buffer-new && org-mode"
> ```

More like:

> ```
> --eval="(progn (evil-buffer-new) (org-mode))"
> ```

But you'll have to figure it out for yourself, because I don't know what `evil-buffer-new` is specifically.

Comment: Please check out the question update.

Answer (score 0):

You told an empty file is created before emacs is started. But instead of an empty file could you create a file with [file-local mode variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/File-Variables.html) specifying the org mode ? For example with bash:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

cat <<EOF >> "$1"
; -*- mode: Org;-*-
EOF

emacs "$1" &
```

Now the mode is always resolved correctly with [normal major mode selection procedure](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Choosing-Modes.html).